# Display Date in time zone specified in date string

Tags: javascript, date

I have this date coming as string from API

```
{
 "date": "2020-11-05T18:24:00-05:00"
}
```

I want this to be rendered as :

```
November 5, 2020, 6:24:00 PM EST
```

The issue is, I can't extract timezone name from this string to pass to Intl.DateTimeFormat()

Any thoughts?!

Comment: `-05:00` corresponds to 40+ time zones.

Comment: Timezones are messy, the names aren't standardised. It's the offset that matters.

Comment: @RobG is there a standard or a solid way i can achieve desired output indicated in post by getting offset

Comment: @Tarreq—not from just the offset. TLDR: Timezones started out as 15° wide one hour offsets ±GMT. Different places gave them different names (they aren't standardised), even for the same zone. Then some places wanted half hour offsets, some even 15 minute offsets. Then came daylight saving. Everyone wanted to give their offset a name, which became synonymous with timezone. Then came IANA representative locations, which are also called "timezones", even thought they aren't. At least the IANA identifier includes historical offset changes for a particular place. Yeah, it's fun. And maddening. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get `EST` from `-05:00` directly, without defining a context. Indeed, this offset could reference several time zones, see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

In the browser, you can let the time library to guess the time zone of your client:

```
var tz = moment.tz.guess(); // America/New_York, for example
var date = moment("2020-11-05T18:24:00-05:00").tz(tz)
   .format("MMMM D, YYYY, h:mm:ss A z");
console.log(date);    // November 5, 2020, 6:24:00 PM EST
```

Or you can define a time zone yourself.

Of course, the two solutions will not give you the same result depending on the time zone specified.

Comment: In my example, i don't want to render Date in my browser's locale, actually my tz is GMT+2 and what i want is displaying the date with the tz or offset included in the given date string

Comment: You can capture this part like this : `moment.parseZone("2020-11-05T18:24:00-05:00").format("Z");  // -05:00`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, is it available in moment.js to capture tz name from a date string (i.e. "Africa/Cairo")?

Comment: Not directly, but if performance is not required, you can do :
`var zones = moment.tz.names().map(zone => ({ zone, offset: moment.tz(zone).format('Z') }));
zones.filter(x => x.offset === '-05:00'); 
// [ { zone: 'America/Atikokan', offset: '-05:00' }, { zone: 'America/Bahia_Banderas', offset: '-05:00' }, ... ]`